# A nice escape for ssh

Tags: ssh, telnet

I know I can make a script..but I want
an easy solution like telnet

With telnet:
I have one session on console..and pc remote crash or shutdown.
I press control+alt+] and telnet go into interactive mode
i press q and bye.

With ssh: 
I have one session on console..and pc remote crash or shutdown.
How to exit from freezed session like telnet without using scripts,xargs,etc?

Comment: Read `man ssh_config` and look for `ServerAliveInterval` and `ServerAliveCountMax`.

Comment: Assuming you are talking about interactive `ssh` sessions here: press _[Enter ↵]_, then `~` and then `?` to see the interactive `ssh` commands available and what they do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For an interactive `ssh` using a pseudo-terminal you can type the escape character, by default `~`, followed by `.` to close the connection.  If you have already typed some data you will first need to press return as the escape character is only recognised at the start of a line. Option `-e` changes the escape character. See the man page section on ESCAPE CHARACTERS.

Comment: It's a minor thing, but the escape character needs to be the first character typed after pressing `<Enter>`.